# Alternatives to setting java.library.path?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, java.library.path

I have a Java program making some JNI calls to a native library ("mylib.so"). Whenever I want to run this program, from the command line, I must set java.library.path to the location of my library as such:

```
java -Djava.library.path=/var/natives/ -classpath MyPackage.jar MyPackage.MyClass arg1 arg2
```

I'm wondering if there are any alternatives so I do not have to set it with the -D option everytime I run my program.

I have tried adding `/var/natives/` to my $PATH variable, but it still complains that it cannot find the library if I do not explicitly set it with -D.

Do I have any other options?

Comment: Just put the entire command in a `.sh` file.

Comment: @BalusC, if you want to post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the entire command in a `.sh` file to save yourself from repeating it everytime.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `System.loadLibrary("mylib")`, use `System.load("/var/natives/mylib.so")`.

Or, you could define a custom class loader for the class and override the `ClassLoader.findLibrary(String)` method.

Answer (score 0):

One place you can put it (which admittedly may be suboptimal) is in the `[JRE]/lib/i386` directory (or `[JRE]/lib/x64` or whatever it is called in a 64-bit Java installation).

Also, have you tried putting `/var/natives` in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is creating your own variable with the switches in it. For example:

```
COMPILE="-Djava.library.path=/var/natives/ -classpath /var/packages/MyPackage.jar"
```

Then run the command like:

```
java $COMPILE MyPackage.MyClass arg1 arg2 arg3
```